# "in fact" vs "indeed"

Tags: word-usage

This might sound silly, but are "indeed" and "in fact" interchangeable? Here's a case:

Q: Is that a nice house?

A1: Yes, it's really nice indeed.
A2: Yes, in fact it's really nice.

It sounds to me that on the second one the person who's answering is making a subtle correction (it's not only nice, it's really nice), while in the first one the person is just agreeing.
Does that make sense?

Comment: Nice question bro 

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're detecting the difference in nuance well.

*Indeed* comes from *deed* as in "action" or "fact" (rather than "thought" or "speech") and so the meaning of "in deed" and hence *indeed* is very close to that of "in fact"

But *indeed* is genearlly used to confirm or to introduce something that supports what has already been said, and "in fact" used to deny or introduce something that counters what has already been said.

> We would have expected this to improve matters, and indeed the results were much better.
>
> We would have expected this to improve matters, but in fact the results got worse.

Comment: This is so awesome -- never thought this way!!

Comment: It's interesting that the Latin root "factum" means "deed" or "act". But I guess the word was reshaped as it wedged into the English vernacular.